# Regex TYPO3 Links

Tags: php, regex, typo3

I need to change all TYPO3 Links into real a-Tags, because I want to use it without TYPO3

**Text example #1:**

```
$strText = 'This is a  <strong>full</strong> Text
    <link https://www.example.com/news/test.html#tab3 _blank external-link-new-window "Opens external link in new window">More informations</link><br>
    Some more Text <link http://www.example.com>More informations</link>
    Text end';
```

**I tried the following regex:**

```
$search = '/<link\s(ftp:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/)([^\s]+)[^>]*>(.+?)<\/link>/si';
$replace = '<a href="\\1\\2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="external">\\3</a>';
$strText = preg_replace($search, $replace, $strText);
```

It is working perfectly with this text... However it is very buggy, if the order of the links is inverted inside this text

**Text example #2 which result in problems:**

```
$strText = 'This is a  <strong>full</strong> Text
        <link http://www.example.com>More informations</link><br>
        Some more Text <link https://www.example.com/news/test.html#tab3 _blank external-link-new-window "Opens external link in new window">More informations</link>
        Text end';
```

This results in a incorrect link which wraps both links in one.

I don't understand this and can't find a solution.

Comment: Why not let TYPO3 render the content and use the output? Then you are sure that all links are displayed correctly with target, title, link content, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
/<link\s(ftp:\/\/|https?:\/\/|\/)([^\s]+)[^>]*>(.+?)<\/link>/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer was a very good hint, but that regex was not working for links that have no more attributes other than the href e.g. (<link [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1example/edit#gid=3333333>](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1example/edit#gid=3333333%3E)**some text**)

This worked fine:

```
<link(\s(ftp:\/\/|https?:\/\/|\/)([^\s>]+))[^>]*>(.+?)<\/link>
```